# Django: `create()` did not return an object instance

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a comment in a restful API, using Django 1.11.2. Currently i am fallowing the tutorial "Blog API with Django Rest Framework" from "CodingEntrepreneurs". I don't know what the problem is.

This the serializer code:

```
def create_comment_serializer(model_type='post', slug=None, parent_id=None, user=None):
    class CommentCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = [
                'id',
                'content',
                'timestamp',
            ]
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.model_type = model_type
            self.slug = slug
            self.parent_obj = None
            if parent_id:
                parent_qs = Comment.objects.filter(id=parent_id)
                if parent_qs.exists() and parent_qs.count() ==1:
                    self.parent_obj = parent_qs.first()
            return super(CommentCreateSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def validate(self, data):
            model_type = self.model_type
            model_qs = ContentType.objects.filter(model=model_type)
            if not model_qs.exists() or model_qs.count() != 1:
                raise ValidationError("This is not a valid content type")
            SomeModel = model_qs.first().model_class()
            obj_qs = SomeModel.objects.filter(slug=self.slug)
            if not obj_qs.exists() or obj_qs.count() != 1:
                raise ValidationError("This is not a slug for this content type")
            return data

        def create(self, validated_data):
            content = validated_data.get("content")
            if user:
                main_user = user
            else:
                main_user = User.objects.all().first()
            model_type = self.model_type
            slug = self.slug
            parent_obj = self.parent_obj
            comment = Comment.objects.create_by_model_type(
                model_type, slug, content, main_user,
                parent_obj=parent_obj
            )
            return comment

    return CommentCreateSerializer
```

this is the view code:

```
class CommentCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    #serializer_class = PostCreateUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        model_type = self.request.GET.get("type")
        slug = self.request.GET.get("slug")
        parent_id = self.request.GET.get("parent_id", None)
        return create_comment_serializer(
                model_type=model_type,
                slug=slug,
                parent_id=parent_id,
                user=self.request.user
                )
```

Comment: What does `ContentType.objects.filter(model=model_type)` yield? Because if you use the original [`create_by_model_type()`](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Blog-API-with-Django-Rest-Framework/blob/ebce1ea22d6a70325c0f18ede52f44dc9a4671d5/src/comments/models.py#L36) it returns `None` when the type was not found.

Comment: thanks! didn't saw the error there, was focused only on the api.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your `Comment.objects.create_by_model_type()` is not creating any object and `create()` method didn't found anything to return.